# jquery adding a span to a group of letters in a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was trying to design a log in front end with some wave effect to make the letters of the label move in a wave shape but I can't get the span tag to be added dynamically to the letters
I will put the HTML and jQuery code then the CSS code and finally the DOM code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>login wave effect</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="code.jquery.com_jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Please Login</h1>
        <form>
            <div class="form-container">
                <input type="text" required >
                <label for="input">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-container">
                <input type="password" required>
                <label for="input">Password</label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        <p class="text">
            Don't have an account? <a href="#">Register</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <!--<script>
        $(".form-container label").each(function(){
            $(this).html = $(this)
            .text()
            .split("")
            .map(function(element,idx){
                `<span style="transition-delay:${idx*50}ms">${element}</span>`})
            .join('')
        });
    </script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

this is the DOM Code

```js
var labels = document.querySelectorAll(".form-container label");
labels.forEach(function(label){
    label.innerHTML = innerText
    .split("")
    .map(function(element,idx){
        `<span style="transition-delay:${idx*50}ms">${element}</span>`})
    .join('');
 });
```

This is the CSS code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family:'Muli', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(44, 88, 124);
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.btn{
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    padding :10px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    color: aliceblue;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.btn:active{
    outline: 0;
    transform: scale(0.95);
    background-color: rgb(83, 20, 142);
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 10px 0 30px;
}
.form-container{
    margin:20px 0px 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
.form-container input{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px white solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: bisque;
}
.form-container input:focus,
.form-container input:valid{
    outline: 0;
}
.text{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.text a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(30, 3, 8);
}
.form-container label{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
.form-container label span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.form-container input:focus + label span,
.form-container input:valid + label span{
    transform: translateY(-40px);
}
```

Comment: It hasn't been necessary to put a script in an HTML comment for decades.

Comment: Are you doing this in jQuery or vanilla JS? Where do you define `innerText`? Is that supposed to be `label.innerText`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `map` function is missing the `return` statement, also the `innerText` is not defined in the given script i don't know if you just didn't mention it in this code.

the script should be:

```
let innerText = "";//get the value from somewhere
var labels = document.querySelectorAll(".form-container label");
labels.forEach(function(label){
    label.innerHTML = innerText
    .split("")
    .map(function(element,idx){
        //here the return statement
        return `<span style="transition-delay:${idx*50}ms">${element}</span>`;})
    .join('');
 });
```

Comment: i tried and it is not working

Comment: <script>
        $(".form-container label").each(function(){
            $(this).html = $(this)
            .text()
            .split("")
            .map(function(element,idx){
               return `<span style="transition-delay:${idx*50}ms">${element}</span>`})
            .join('')
        });
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfect case for using CSS var() and CSS calc().
Set the `--idx` CSS var to the element index and multiply it in CSS (animation-delay) by the desired time using `calc()` like: `calc(var(--idx) * 0.2s)`

```js
const labels = document.querySelectorAll(".form-container label");

labels.forEach(function(label) {
  label.innerHTML = [...label.textContent].map((char, idx) => {
    return `<span style="--idx:${idx};">${char}</span>`;
  }).join("");
});
```

```css
form label span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: wave 1s linear calc(var(--idx) * 0.2s) alternate infinite;
  translate: 0 -30%;
}

@keyframes wave {
  to { translate: 0 30%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Please Login</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="form-container">
      <input type="text" required>
      <label for="input">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container">
      <input type="password" required>
      <label for="input">Password</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
  <p class="text">
    Don't have an account? <a href="#">Register</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

also, notice that `.map()` should have an either direct or implicit `return` statement. Also, `innerText` is not defined and set. You meant to use Element.textContent instead (which BTW is preferred over Element.innerText).